# Print Problem: Page Squeezed in Half

Tags: printing, canon

I've just managed to successfully set up my printer (Canon MX320) using the Printing app on Ubuntu 12.04. However the only 1 remaining problem is that each time I tried to print it will only print the file on the top half of the page only: meaning that for some reason, the printer "squeezes" the whole content of each page in the file to fit into the top half of the page only (so the proportion in the print-out is not correct vertically).

This happens with every type of file I tried to print (Documents, Images, Web pages). I checked the Printing's setting & properties and couldn't find anything related to this issue yet and I've already made sure to set all the information correct (paper size, source etc.).

The Print Preview always display correctly on the screen, but it's only the actual print-out that shows this problem. I also tried with several different types of papers (A4, photos etc.) but the result is always the same: the printer keeps putting the content in the top half of the paper only.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks very much for your tips! I finally realized too that I indeed had an incorrect driver installed.

My printer is Canon MX328 and when "Printing" tried to install the driver for me it could only find drivers for MX300 and MX330 series, so it "recommended" me to use the MX300 one, which apparently turns out to be the cause of the incorrect print-out.

I finally found the MX320's Linux driver from Canon web site but in DEB format, while Ubuntu's Printing requires only PPD format when installing driver manually. Double-clicking the DEB file does not automatically install the file (it only opens in text editor) so I had to work still more around it to open it in Software Center in order to successfully install the driver and get the correct print-out. Not sure why Ubuntu did not make this more convenient for user, but finally for me the problem's solved now.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a very similar problem (the printable area was "squeezed" to the left-hand side of the page only).  My printer is an HP Officejet Pro 8500.  When installing the printer (within Ubuntu 12.04), I used the driver recommended by Ubuntu through the printing utility.  Even though the driver seemed outdated (model 1175 instead of my model, which was an 8500), it was the most-recent driver.

To resolve the issue, I changed the driver.  I used a driver that was a generation or two older (selected through the print utility tool).  Although printing speed seemed to decrease, my printable area was once again normal.  HP needs to update the Ubuntu drivers, which probably is not high on their priority list.